# Javascript regex replace every other comma with semicolon

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string of times like `5:11,14:00,17:11,22:00`.

I need to replace every other comma with a semicolon to get `5:11,14:00;17:11,22:00`.

What would the regex be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var times = '5:11,14:00,17:11,22:00';
times.replace(/(,[^,]*),/g, '$1;');
```